# Topology in space of Lipschitz functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X$ be a normed space and $L> 0$ be fixed. Consider the set

$$Li_L(X,\mathbb{R})= \{f: X\to \mathbb{R}: |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L\|x-y\|\;\forall \; x,y\in X\}.$$ I am looking for well known topologies on $Li_L.$ Any reference will also be nice.

Comment: If you also put a bound on f then this becomes a ball in the Holder space $C^{0,1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When considering Lipschitz functions on a normed space $X$, one usually normalizes them by $f(0)= 0$. The space of all normalized Lipschitz functions is called the *Lipschitz dual* of $X$, denoted $X^\#$. It briefly appears in the book *Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis* by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss. With a search for "Lipschitz dual", "normed space" you'll find more, e.g. [this paper](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~studia-m/2003-1/cobzas2.pdf).

The space $X^\#$ is a Banach space with the norm $\|f\| = \sup_{a\ne b} |f(a)-f(b)|/\|a-b\|$.

The natural topologies of $X^\#$ are:

- the norm topology,
- the topology of pointwise convergence (which makes closed balls in $X^\#$ compact). It's mentioned in [Lipschitz p-summing Operators](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bill.johnson/Lip-p-summing10.pdf) by Farmer and Johnson.
- the weak* topology, in case it's different from the above (I'm not sure); this
  is defined because $X^\#$ has a canonical pre-dual constructed by Arens and Eells in [On embedding uniform and topological spaces](http://msp.org/pjm/1956/6-3/pjm-v6-n3-p01-s.pdf). A more recent paper on this duality is [Duality for Lipschitz p-summing operators](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123611001303) by Javier Alejandro Chávez-Domínguez.

In principle one could consider the weak topology on $X^\#$ (but what is the dual space of $X^\#$ anyway?) and the topology of uniform convergence, but I haven't seen those.

If you do not normalize $f(0)=0$, the result is just a product of $X^\#$ with $X$.

One more reference: the book *Lipschitz Algebras* by Nik Weaver, which carefully discusses how to norm and/or normalize Lipschitz functions.